# Unimodality and continuity for probability distribution

Tags: probability

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vysochanski%C3%AF%E2%80%93Petunin_inequality) about the conditions for the Vysochanskij–Petunin inequality

> The sole restriction on the distribution is that it be unimodal and
>   have finite variance. (**This implies that it is a continuous
>   probability distribution except at the mode, which may have a non-zero
>   probability.**)

Does it mean that unimodality and finite variance imply the distribution is continuous except at the mode? Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $X \sim \operatorname{Binom}\left(2n, \frac{1}{2}\right)$. It is unimodal (with mode at $X=n$) and has finite variance.

Comment: Weakly related but with a different transliteration from Russian: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64945/is-there-one-tailed-version-of-vysochanskiipetunin-inequality-like-chebyshev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finiteness of the variance is irrelevant. As explained by [Sellke and Sellke](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2684690) (see the reference on [the WP page on unimodality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodal_function#Unimodal_function,)), in this context, the *unimodality* of a CDF $F$ with mode $m$ means that $F$ is concave on $[m,+\infty)$ and convex on $(-\infty,m]$. This is an easy exercise to show that any CDF which is unimodal *in this sense* has no jumps except possibly at $m$.

Assuming for example that $F(x-)\lt F(x)$ at some $x\gt m$, one sees that for small values of $\varepsilon\gt0$, the segment between the points on the graph of $F$ with abscissae $x-\varepsilon$ and $x$ is at least partly above the graph. This contradicts the concavity hence $F(x-)=F(x)$ at every $x\gt m$.

In particular, discrete distributions $(p_k)$ on the integers which are unimodal in the sense that $k\mapsto p_k$ is increasing then decreasing, are *not* unimodal in this convexity/concavity sense.

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation is correct.

If you regard some distributions on the integers as unimodal in the natural sense (such as the binomial and Poisson distributions) then the distribution with $$\Pr(X=0)=\frac{1}{2k^2}$$ $$\Pr(X=1)=1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$ $$\Pr(X=2)=\frac{1}{2k^2}$$ has a mean of $1$, a variance of $\frac{1}{k^2}$, and is unimodal when $k \gt \sqrt{\frac32}$. But it is bound by the Chebyshev inequality not the Vysochanskij–Petunin inequality.